# Tinyproxy connects to host machine, maxing out the connection pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, proxy, tinyproxy

I'm trying to set tinyproxy server in AWS so I can later connect to it from a frontend application I build.

I've installed tinyproxy on an ubuntu machine in AWS. For testing purposes I've configured the external ip address to be the proxy address in my firefox browser and I am able to run traffic through it.

The problem is that after a while tinyproxy refuses to accept new connection. When I'm running `service tinyproxy status` I'm getting the following line *"Maximum number of connections reached. Refusing new connections."*. I've set timeout property to 600 and it happened again.

I installed netstat to see what connection are open and this is what I see: [image]

At the bottom of the list I see a similar image, but now the same port numbers that were on local address are on the foreign address:

[image]

Notes:

1. The IP address that is deleted is the external IP address of the AWS machine that tinyproxy is running on. The local address is the private address of the AWS machine.
2. I can see my "normal" connections from the browser when I am connected and I can see that they are deleted when I close the browsers.

My conf file is:

```
User tinyproxy
Group tinyproxy
Port 8888
Timeout 60
DefaultErrorFile "error.txt" 
StatFile "stats.json"  
LogLevel CONNECT 
PidFile "/run/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.pid" 
MaxClients 100
LogFile "/var/log/tinyproxy/tinyproxy.log"
Allow 0.0.0.0/0
Allow 127.0.0.1
Allow ::1
ViaProxyName "tinyproxy"
ConnectPort 443                                                                                                                                                                                  
ConnectPort 563
```

I would appreciate any help figuring out what are those connections and how do I prevent them from maxing out my pool.

Comment: Have you found a reason at some point
I see it in my new proxy as well and I have no idea what establishes so many connections

Comment: I did not find the cause, but I switched to squid instead of tiny, and I didn't change anything else in the settings (same aws machines, acl etc...) and I don't see the same problem, so I suspect it was something in my tiny settings